# How to automate data import on full sandbox refresh

Tags: data-loader, automation, sandbox-refresh, test-automation

I am involved in doing QA in a stage full sandbox environment. I am interested in being able to populate the sandbox with a small amount of consistent (I cant rely on production data) test data. Is there a way to make specific non production data be created/imported automatically after every refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a Full Copy Sandbox , In your production org you will see a Tab named "Sandbox Templates".

> Sandbox templates allow you to pick specific objects and data to copy to your Full or Partial Copy sandbox to control the size and content of each sandbox.

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5) is the official docs to help you set up the sandbox templates .You will need to create these templates and associate , so that every time you do a refresh the sample data is populated .

It will be a random dataset from your PROD org .

Ideally would recommend a partial sandbox because the refresh interval is small rather than Full Copy which you will have to wait longer to refresh .

If you want to further automate it , you will need to use dataloader and its [command line capability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/using_the_command_line_interface.htm) to script so that you can automatically upload it .

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to take the time, the [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) interface lets you write code that's called once upon refresh. You could write a bunch of code to populate records. If you're planning on moving to DX, force:data:import lets you import JSON files into your orgs using the new [SObject Tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm), which automatically creates records *and* associates them with their parent records automatically, which is simple compared to using the Apex Data Loader CLI.